# Can a salesforce app include optional components?

Tags: salesforce

I am working on a Salesforce App. It includes a feature (a public facing web page) that requires an Enterprise Edition account.

Excluding this feature, the app should run on all other Salesforce Editions.

I'm worried that by packaging this feature, the App will become uninstallable to "Pro" and "Group" users.  Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can apparently make use of any Salesforce features without restriction when installed on any Org edition to avoid incompatibility issues. That said, I wouldn't expect the public page to be available on lower editions as it would require more configuration to be exposed, but if it's not essential to your app then I guess you'll be ok.

Comment: That's good to know.  I was unable to install a test version that was using APEX code on a Group account.  But, I think this is because it wasn't a managed package.  I've since created a managed package.  I'll see how it goes.